# i made Lambda function make a response from S3 but i dont know how to return the payload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I made **ALB-lambda-S3** structure.
and i assign valid IAM at lambda

but at the Lamda function , i couldnt make a valid response .
and got 504 gateway error

to check by my self i added debugging code

sorry !!!  maybe this is ALB error. i would check

**-------- (please ignore)-----------------**

```
console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

and got a valid keys

```
  'AcceptRanges',
  'LastModified',
  'ContentLength',
  'ETag',
  'ContentType',
  'ServerSideEncryption',
  'Metadata',
  'Body'
```

but failed body: data.Body.toString('base64')

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3 = new S3Client({region: 'ap-southeast-2'})


export const handler = async (event) => {
     const path = event.path;

    if (path === "/lp/test.pdf") {
        
        const command = new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: 'test-bucket',
            Key: 'lp/test.pdf'
        });
        
        try {
            
            const data = await s3.send(command);      

            // here are logs like above　★★
            console.log(Object.keys(data));
            

            // this response is failed ...　★★
            const response = {
                 statusCode: 200,
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                 },
                 // maybe parsing of here might be wrong?? ★★
                 body: data.Body.toString('base64'),
                 isBase64Encoded: true,
            };

            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            return {
                 statusCode: 500,
                 body: JSON.stringify(error),
            };
        }
    } else {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the cases when ALB returns 504 is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-504-issues)

> The target returns a content-length header that is larger than the entity body. The load balancer timed out waiting for the missing bytes.

Can it be that since you set `headers` manually it misses `ContentLength` and therefore ends with timeout? Try setting `ContentLength` header to match size of base64 encoded body you are passing back.